# Spring MVC: Multiple Select Controls with the Same Name

Tags: java, spring-mvc, command, form-submit

I have a screen in a Spring 2.5 application I'm working on that has 1 to 10 select controls with the same name. (The number of controls rendered depends on the number of relevant objects passed to the screen.) Let's say the select control's name is **myValue**, i.e.,

`<select id="myValue" name="myValue" cssclass="dropDownList">`

Is there a way to make Spring MVC automatically set the value for these controls in my command class? I've tried to defined the data member as either `String [] myValue` or `String myValue`, but in either case, the data member remains set to null. Do I need to resort to concatenating these values within Javascript and saving them to a hidden input prior to submitting the form values back to the controller?

Comment: what do you mean by 'with the same name, depending on the data passed to the screen' ?

Comment: I've edited the question to clear up any confusion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going the Javascript route and still not getting my values returned to the controller, I finally realized my problem was due to programmer error: I had defined a getter and setter for the `myValue` data member of my command class but I had defined them as `private`. Once I switched those to the `public` designation Spring-MVC was expecting, I was finally able to see the values in my controller method in the form of a String array...